# TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Tags: python, python-3.x

He estado mirando otros problemas y no me han resuelto nada, así que os digo que me pasa. Estoy intentando escribir el email y la contraseña en un txt pero me salta el error del título, una vez lo arregle pero lo que hacía era borra lo que había y escribir lo nuevo. Este es el código que tengo

```
f = open('accounts.txt', 'wb')
str(email)
f.write(email + ':' + e2 + '\n')
f.close()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si abres el archivo en modo binario(`wb`), el método `write` espera un objeto `bytes` y no un objeto `str`. Un objeto  `str` en Python 3 es una cadena (texto), una secuencia, de caracteres. Concretamente son una secuencia de puntos de código [unicode (UTF-8)](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8).

Suponiendo que tanto `email` como `e2` sean `str`, debes codificar primero para obtener un objeto `bytes`.

Por otro lado, el modo `w` trunca el archivo antes de escribir en él si ya existía, para que no elimine lo que el archivo contenía debes usar el modo `a` (`append`), no `w`. Al final dejo un breve resumen de los modos d apertura disponibles en Python.

```
with open('accounts.txt', 'ab') as f:
    f.writelines((email.encode(), b":", e2.encode(), b"\n"))
```

Aunque en tal caso, simplemente abre el archivo en modo texto:

```
with open('accounts.txt', 'a') as f:
    f.write(f"{email}:{e2}\n")
```

Para aclarar, los posibles modos de apertura son:

- **`'r'`**: modo lectura, por defecto.
- **`'w'`**: modo escritura, si el archivo ya existe lo trunca eliminando todo su contenido, si no existe lo crea.
- **`'x'`**: creación exclusiva, si el archivo ya existe falla con un `FileExistsError`, en caso contrario lo crea.
- **`'a'`**: modo escritura, si no existe el archivo lo crea, si existe añade el nuevo contenido al final del mismo.
- **`'b'`**: modo binario (`ab`, `rb`, `wb`, `xb`).
- **`'t'`**: modo texto, por defecto (`at`, `rt`, `wt`, `xt`).
- **`'+'`**: permite escritura y lectura simultánea (`w+`, `r+`, `a+`, `ab+`, `rb+`, `wb+`, `xb+`, `at+`, `rt+`, `wt+`, `xt+`).

Comment: Sigue borrando el texto que había en el archivo, es decir si en el archivo ponía: _mekaxan429@itiomail.com_ ahora pone _tidoyad788@fft-mail.com_, no se añade a una fila abajo si no que elimina el contenido

Comment: P.D edita el segundo código porfa, hay un ) de más y podría causar confusión para lo que vengan a buscar la respuesta

Comment: Hola, typo corregido, gracias. En cuanto a lo otro, solo tienes que abrir el archivo en modo  "a". Corregido también.

Comment: Okay muchas gracias por todo